# How to implement Combination and Permutation in RISC-V

Tags: assembly, riscv

Like the code below, I have problem with how to implement Combination and Permutation in RISC-V

I want the output to be:

> s1113310
>
> input number M=4
>
> input number N=2
>
> P(M,N)=12
>
> C(M,N)=6

but instead, the result is:

> s1113310
>
> input number M=4
>
> input number N=2
>
> P(M,N)=24
>
> C(M,N)=6

can someone can show me where the code is wrong and how to fix it.

```
.data
str1: .string "s1113310"
m: .string "\ninput number M="
n: .string "input number N="
p_result: .string "P(M,N)="
c_result: .string "C(M,N)="

.text
main:
    la a0, str1
    li a7, 4
    ecall

    la a0, m
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    li a7, 5
    ecall
    mv s0, a0  # s0 = M

    la a0, n
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    li a7, 5
    ecall
    mv s1, a0  # s1 = N

    mv a0, s0
    jal factorial
    mv s2, a0  # s2 = M!

    sub a0, s0, s1
    jal factorial
    mv s3, a0  # s3 = (M-N)!

    div s4, s2, s3  # s4 = P(M,N) = M! / (M-N)!
    jal pp
    
    mv a0, s1
    jal factorial
    mv s5, a0  # s5 = N!

    mul s6, s3, s5  # s6 = (M-N)! * N!
    div s7, s2, s6  # s7 = C(M,N) = M! / ((M-N)! * N!)
    jal pc

    j end

pp:
    la a0, p_result
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    mv a0, s4
    li a7, 1
    ecall
    li a0, '\n'
    li a7, 11
    ecall
    ret

pc:
    la a0, c_result
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    mv a0, s7
    li a7, 1
    ecall
    li a0, '\n'
    li a7, 11
    ecall
    ret

factorial:
    li t0, 1
    mv t1, a0
loop:
    bge t0, t1, endfactorial
    mul a0, a0, t1
    addi t1, t1, -1
    j loop
endfactorial:
    ret

end:
    li a7, 10
    ecall
```

Edit:
I have solved this issue, here's the code:

```
.data
str1: .string "s1113310\\n"
m: .string "input number M="
n: .string "input number N="
p_result: .string "P(M,N)="
c_result: .string "C(M,N)=" 
h_result: .string "H(M,N)="
mn_result: .string "M^N="

.text
main:
    la a0, m
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    li a7, 5
    ecall
    mv s0, a0

    # 輸入 n
    la a0, n
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    li a7, 5
    ecall
    mv s1, a0

    li t0,0
    #P(n, k) = n! / (n-k)!
    mv a0, s0
    jal factorial
    mv s2, a0
    sub a0, s0, s1
    jal factorial
    div s2, s2, a0
    mv s3, s2
    jal pp

    #C(n, k) = n! / (k! * (n-k)!)
    mv a0, s1
    jal factorial
    div s3, s3, a0
    jal pc

    #H(M,N) = C(M+N-1,N) = (M+N-1)! / (N! * (M-1)!)
    add t0, s0, s1
    addi t0, t0, -1
    mv a0, t0
    jal factorial
    mv s4, a0
    mv a0, s1
    jal factorial
    mv t1, a0
    mv a0, s0
    addi a0, a0, -1
    jal factorial
    mul t1, t1, a0
    div s4, s4, t1
    jal ph

    #M^N
    mv a0, s0
    mv a1, s1
    jal power
    mv s5, a0
    jal pmn

    j end

pp:
    la a0, p_result
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    mv a0, s3
    li a7, 1
    ecall
    li a0, '\n'
    li a7, 11
    ecall
    ret

pc:
    la a0, c_result
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    mv a0, s3
    li a7, 1
    ecall
    li a0, '\n'
    li a7, 11
    ecall
    ret

ph:
    la a0, h_result
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    mv a0, s4
    li a7, 1
    ecall
    li a0, '\n'
    li a7, 11
    ecall
    ret

pmn:
    la a0, mn_result
    li a7, 4
    ecall
    mv a0, s5
    li a7, 1
    ecall
    li a0, '\n'
    li a7, 11
    ecall
    ret

factorial:
    li t0, 1
    mv t1,a0
    addi t1,t1,-1
loop:
    bge t0, t1, endfactorial
    mul a0, a0, t1
    addi t1, t1, -1
    jal x0, loop
endfactorial:
    jr ra

power:
    li t0, 1
    mv t1, a1
loop_pow:
    beq t1, zero, end_pow
    mul t0, t0, a0
    addi t1, t1, -1
    j loop_pow
end_pow:
    mv a0, t0
    jr ra

end:
    li a7, 10
    ecall
```

I am still trying to solve H(M,N)

Comment: Do you have a version in a language you know well, and are translating from?  If not, find/make one, make sure it works by testing it.  Then you can debug the assembly side-by-side to make sure it is doing what you want and expect.  Failing that, test with the smallest possible inputs, test piece parts like factorial with small inputs, then slightly larger.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thanks for your reply. I am new to assembly language and I am trying to learn how to use it, it's so different from C/C++ I am still trying to get used to it. I currently use RARS to debug.

Comment: Debugging in assembly language is has much similarity to debugging in high level language.  Single step each line and verify that it's doing what you want and expect.  When you have a working and tested C or Java version to compare with, then you will know immediately when something is going wrong as the high level language and the assembly language will diverge in state or control flow.  Either way, high level language and assembly language are both implementing the same algorithm so should work the same in the large.